# Spring finds a test class on a jar and I get a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, scala

I have a project that uses Spring. The project consists on two different parts, the generic part and the specific one. The generic part is compiled as a .jar, it defines a set of traits and it's used as a dependency by the specific part, which is the one that implements the methods.

In order to test the generic part, I have created a "fake" implementation of one of the trait (let's say "fakeMethodA"), under the test directory of the generic project and I annotated this fake implementation with the `@Component` annotation. I'm getting the beans using the application context.

The problem comes when I try to use this generic part on the specific project. Since my actual implementation of this trait (let's say "methodAImplementation") also has a `@Component` annotation, when I run my tests I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
expected single matching bean but found 2:
```

It finds the `fakeMethodA` from the generic part and `methodAImplementation` from the implementation. Is there any way to exclude this "fake" implementation from the execution? Is there a better way to define this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you somehow depending on generic tests artifact? Or did you include tests of generic part in the generic "runtime" artifact somehow?

Comment: You should probably not see your generic test component from the specific code. But if for some reason, you have to, then at least use specific packages and build your application context to only load the packages that make sense.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @GaëlJ. I solved it with the use of Profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by the use of `@Profile` annotation on the generic method.
I annotated the fake method on the tests with:

```
@Profile(value = Array("Test"))
```

And the right implementation with another profile value. After that, when I select the bean from the context, I can select the correct profile.